# Standard deviation of difference between dates in pandas group by

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, standard-deviation

I have a dataframe of transactions. One of my columns is the date (datetime64[ns]). I'm making a group by of users (email as id). Something I'm interested in is the variability of time between orders of each user. So what I'm looking for in the group by is to find the standard deviation of the difference between dates (in days) for each user. If the user has two or least transactions the answer should be 0. This is some of the dataframe (I changed some things manually):

```
df

                  email                       date
0                 cuadros.paolo@gmail.com     2018-05-01 12:29:59
1                   rlez_1202@hotmail.com     2018-07-11 13:43:22
2                 cuadros.paolo@gmail.com     2018-09-21 12:29:23
3             paola.alvarado@rumah.com.pe     2018-09-01 09:21:43
4                    luchosuito@gmail.com     2018-04-30 12:29:30
5             paola.alvarado@rumah.com.pe     2018-03-22 12:29:23
6           davida.alvarado.703@gmail.com     2018-07-21 12:29:17
7                 cuadros.paolo@gmail.com     2018-08-11 12:29:41
8                   rlez_1202@hotmail.com     2018-05-23 12:29:14
9                    luchosuito@gmail.com     2018-06-01 12:29:17
10               jessica26011@hotmail.com     2018-07-18 12:29:20
11                cuadros.paolo@gmail.com     2018-08-21 12:29:40
12                  rlez_1202@hotmail.com     2018-10-01 12:29:31
13            paola.alvarado@rumah.com.pe     2018-06-01 12:29:20
14              miluska-paico@hotmail.com     2018-05-21 12:29:18
15             cinthia_leon87@hotmail.com     2018-07-20 12:29:59
```

I've tried many ways, but still can't get it. Please help.

Comment: And what happens when the user has more than 2 dates? Are we doing all pairwise combinations, or just the sequential differences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For sequential differences, which seems to make the most sense given your explanation:

```
df.sort_values('date').groupby('email').apply(lambda x: x.date.diff().std()).fillna(0)
```

#### Output:

```
email
cinthia_leon87@hotmail.com              0 days 00:00:00
cuadros.paolo@gmail.com         48 days 05:04:12.988006
davida.alvarado.703@gmail.com           0 days 00:00:00
jessica26011@hotmail.com                0 days 00:00:00
luchosuito@gmail.com                    0 days 00:00:00
miluska-paico@hotmail.com               0 days 00:00:00
paola.alvarado@rumah.com.pe     14 days 18:10:16.764069
rlez_1202@hotmail.com           23 days 06:17:04.453408
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

`.std()` will be null for groups with 1 value non-null value and since .`diff` reduces the number of non-null observations by 1, this automatically returns `NaN` for any groups with 2 or fewer measurements, which we fill with 0.

Also just be aware that the default for `pandas` is to use `N-1` degrees of freedom.

Comment: `.diff()` computes the first difference of the dates in each group (i.e., current row – previous row), but what's needed here is to subtract the same (arbitrary) date from each date.

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler it's a bit ambiguous. They want "the variability of time between orders of each user". So in my case, I calculate the time between orders (sequentially), and then find the variability. I think this makes more sense because in your calculation the standard deviation inherently grows as users continue to place more orders. I.e. someone with orders from 2011 to 2017 will have more 'variability` in your definition than somoene with orders between 2016-2017, even if they place an order every week.

Comment: My understanding is that the standard deviation to be calculated is for the difference between the actual dates of consecutives orders. I think ALollz solution is right. All you need to add is a sort after the groupby and before the apply AND a fillna(0) at the end to make the NaN zeros.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I was looking for.